# C beginner, pointers & dereferencing

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I am trying to understand this whole pointer and dereference thing in C. I almost got it, but bumped into pretty simple code, which result I don't understand:

```
char *ptr = "Characters";
char val = *ptr;
char *chrptr = &val;
printf("Value under character pointer is: %p / %c\n", &val, val);
printf("Dereferenced character pointer: %p\n", chrptr);
printf("Array pointer: %p\n", ptr);
```

Now, as I understood before execution, `ptr == chrptr == &val`, but in reality `ptr != chrptr == &val`. Why is this?

Comment: The first line is poor C. It should be `char const * ptr = "Characters";`. Make sure you really understand this. (But that's not related to your question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *ptr = "Characters"; // returns a pointer to 'C'
char val = *ptr; // dereferences the pointer to 'C' and copies 'C' into val
```

*val* has its own memory location, so the **address of *val* will be different**

```
 char *chrptr = &val; //chptr points to val. A different memory location.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char *ptr = "Characters";

       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+ 
ptr -> | C | h | a | r | a | c | t | e | r | s | \0 |
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+ 

char val = *ptr; // you copy 'C' by value from the array, ptr is still pointing 
                 // where it originally pointed

// &val is somewhere else in memory so

char *chrptr = &val;

          +---+ 
chrptr -> | C |
          +---+
```

if you want have chrptr point where ptr points then write

```
char* chrptr = ptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign to a `char`,  a copy is made. So the address of that copy will not be equal to the original string.

In contrast, when you assign to a pointer, you are assigning the address of the original string (or whatever it's a pointer to).

Answer (score 1):

```
ptr == chrptr == &val
```

Only `chrptr == &val` part is correct, but `ptr != chrptr`. This is because `val` is a *copy* of the first character from `ptr`, i.e. `'C'`. The copy is stored at a different place from the original, so its address in memory is different.

Answer (score 0):

String "Characters" is located by compiler in one memory area, but variable "val" (which is equal to 'C') is located in other memory area. That's why &val is not equal to "ptr".

Answer (score 0):

Never mind all the indirection and local variables, but your problem boils down to the same as this one:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
```

Both `a` and `b` have the same value, but they're obviously different objects, and so they have different addresses. The same is true of  `val` and `ptr[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does the following.

```
char *ptr = "Characters"; //- Store "Characters" in read only data section and assign the address to variable to `ptr`.

char val = *ptr; //- Assign the value 'C' (i.e 67) to stack variable val.

char *chrptr = &val; //- Assign the address of variable val to chrptr
```

Here `val` is a stack variable hence the address of it will be in stack address range. But the string literal is stored in read-only-data section. And only ptr holds the address of that.

So obviously `&val` and `ptr` are two different addresses.